# VSTS, NuGet Failed to download package (GatewayTimeout)?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a VS2017 solution that I would like to build with VSTS, but the NuGet restore step fails with:

```
2017-07-14T07:25:30.8403126Z Installing System.Net.WebSockets.Client 4.0.0.
2017-07-14T07:25:40.0651944Z   GatewayTimeout https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime/4.3.0/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.4.3.0.nupkg 11993ms
2017-07-14T07:25:40.0662422Z Failed to download package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime/4.3.0/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.4.3.0.nupkg'.
2017-07-14T07:25:40.0662422Z Response status code does not indicate success: 504 (Gateway Timeout).
2017-07-14T07:25:40.0662422Z   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime/4.3.0/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.4.3.0.nupkg
2017-07-14T07:25:43.3028714Z Installing System.Numerics.Vectors.WindowsRuntime 4.0.1.
2017-07-14T07:25:52.0318944Z   GatewayTimeout https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime/4.3.0/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.4.3.0.nupkg 11964ms
2017-07-14T07:25:52.0338545Z Failed to download package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.4.3.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime/4.3.0/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.4.3.0.nupkg'.
2017-07-14T07:25:52.0338545Z Response status code does not indicate success: 504 (Gateway Timeout).
2017-07-14T07:25:52.0379675Z Unable to load package 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime'.
2017-07-14T07:25:52.9150812Z ##[error]Error: d:\a\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\4.0.0\NuGet.exe failed with return code: 1
2017-07-14T07:25:52.9150812Z ##[error]Packages failed to install
```

I have tried running the build several times, but it failes downloading the same packages. I have no problem downloading these packages to my own computer using a web browser. I'm using the "Hosted VS2017" build agent.

Comment: I am getting the same error from today (identical build worked yesterday). For me the package was hangfire.sqlserver.1.6.7 but if I put in the `api.nuget.org` address directly the package does download.

Comment: I made a test with .net core console app with System.Net.WebSockets.Client package, it works fine with Hosted VS2017 build agent. What's your project? What's the result now?

Comment: Hey OlavT, was also having the same exact problem as you, and those error logs seem to indicate that there is an error connecting to the nuget.org site for your packages. Give it a few minutes and try it again. This solved the problem for me.